# Checking if an edge is an element of a list of edges

Tags: list-manipulation, graphs-and-networks, conditional

I have graph whose edge list is given by

```
edges = {1 \[UndirectedEdge] 1, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 5}
```

I'm finding that the 'If' statement

```
If[(1 \[UndirectedEdge] 1) ∈ edges,1,0]
```

does not return 1, as expected, or even return zero. It simply spits back the full conditional,

```
If[1 \[UndirectedEdge] 1 ∈ {1 \[UndirectedEdge] 1, 
   1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 
   1 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 5}, 1, 0]
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: try `If[MemberQ[edges, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 1`], 1, 0]`?

Comment: also `Boole @ EdgeQ[Graph@edges,1 \[UndirectedEdge] 1]`

Answer (score 4):

`Element[a,dom]` tests whether `a` is an element of the domain `Dom`.  The documentation for the function lists what those domains might be, things like `Reals` and `Integers`, but not lists that you have defined yourself.  So, for example

`1 \[Element] {1, 2, 3}`

also returns unevaluated whereas

`1 \[Element] Integers`

returns

`True`.

And I see that @kglr has already told you what to do, use `MemberQ` to test membership of arbitrary lists, thusly

`If[MemberQ[edges, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 1], 1, 0]`

which returns

`True`.

Comment: ah, thanks a lot!